# unable to run Time dependent workflow with these conditions

Tags: apex, community, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Hi I'm new to sfdc and I'm unable to run a time dependent workflow.

My requirement is whenever close date of opportunity equals today & stage !=closed won or closed lost i have to do a time dependent workflow action to send an email to owner of that opportunity.

I am providing my images below can you help me.Where i have been wrong

[image: workflow rule criteria]

[image: Time trigger]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need 2 and 3 criterias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the Entry Criteria from the Time Trigger. The criteria for the rule should just be the Stage, and maybe to check that the Close Date is in the future.

```
Close Date greater than or equal to TODAY
Stage not equal to Closed Won,Closed Lost
```

Then the time trigger will run on that future date:

```
0 days before Close Date
```

Comment: It Works like a charm thanks.I customize my workflow based on your answer and the email alert is scheduled in time based workflow.i have small doubt what happened to old records with same criteria @Jeremy Nottingham

Comment: Thanks i got it @Jeremy Nottingham  Can i sent another mail alert to user if user didn't change the close date.

Comment: But i have small correction in your trigger is After.We can't create before trigger in this scenario based on criteria @Jeremy Nottingham